# Repeater shows same values from many to many tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, asprepeater

Sorry for Bad Post and English,I am new at stackoverflow.

I have write a complicate SQL comment to union tables that contains many to many tables also.

When I execute to query it returns correct data. I am using this view in repeater. It shows same values from ManytoMany tables. I've tried everything I know, but couldn't solve my problem. I hope You can understand what I mean. I've added codes and results.

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY secID,ListID,ord) ROW_NUM, *
FROM  (SELECT        dbo.MotorList.section_id AS 'secId' ,dbo.MDIsignal.name AS Sname, dbo.MotorList.mList_id AS 'ListID', dbo.MotorType.name AS Type, dbo.Project.project_id, dbo.Section.code, dbo.MotorList.Mindex AS 'Index', dbo.MotorList.stat AS 'Stat', dbo.MotorList.description

FROM            dbo.MDI INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MDIsignal ON dbo.MDI.mDIsgnl_id = dbo.MDIsignal.mDIsgnl_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MotorList ON dbo.MDI.mList_id = dbo.MotorList.mList_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Section ON dbo.MotorList.section_id = dbo.Section.section_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Project ON dbo.Section.project_id = dbo.Project.project_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MotorType ON dbo.MotorList.motor_id = dbo.MotorType.motor_id
  UNION 
SELECT        dbo.MotorList.section_id AS 'secId' ,dbo.MDOsignal.name AS Sname, dbo.MotorList.mList_id AS 'ListID', dbo.MotorType.name AS 'Type', dbo.Project.project_id, dbo.Section.code, dbo.MotorList.Mindex AS 'Index', dbo.MotorList.stat AS 'Stat', dbo.MotorList.description 

FROM        dbo.MDO INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MDOsignal ON dbo.MDO.mDOsgnl_id = dbo.MDOsignal.mDOsgnl_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MotorList ON dbo.MDO.mList_id = dbo.MotorList.mList_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Section ON dbo.MotorList.section_id = dbo.Section.section_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Project ON dbo.Section.project_id = dbo.Project.project_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MotorType ON dbo.MotorList.motor_id = dbo.MotorType.motor_id
)a
```

[Here correct values that return SQL](https://image.ibb.co/mHDkmz/sqllist.png)

Here how I bind repeater to view:

```
        var list = db.SignalList_S.Where(a => a.secId == sec_id).ToList();
        RptListe.DataSource = list;
        RptListe.DataBind();
```

[Here what shows repeater same values](https://image.ibb.co/duepeK/list.png)

I have marked up some values to show easier.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @Hakan If you see the sql output correctly there are three records as well. The only thing which has changed in sql output and repeater output is the order in which the records have  appeared. See Row Number 2 10 and 15 in sql output

Comment: @akshay if I get  what you mean correctly,I checked the row_num in repeater but its not because of that. these 'active' values from diffirends rows .its ordered by listID .The problem is It cant fetch data from many to many table .Repeater takes first one for own list of many to many and show that. for example .  a ,b,c  -> a,a,a

Comment: I have solved the problem.I added Entity Key. I thought Using Row_Num as PK is enough.

Comment: ""Setting correct EntityKeys is a must for getting correct results from SQL Server, because EntityKeys are used as an internal caching key.""